# SQL Server Select DateTime using like keyword

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple table.

[image: Booking Table]

I am trying to fire following select query on this table.

```
select * 
from booking
where bookingdate like '%11%'
```

In output I expect both the records to be displayed. However, to my surprise only top record from the table is displayed.

This behaviour is quite strange. Is it that `like` keyword doesn't operate properly on `DateTime` type of column?

**EDIT:**

However if I try this (converting `DateTime` to `Varchar`)

```
select * 
from booking
where convert(varchar(50), BookingDate, 120) like '%11%'
```

It works!!

Comment: `DATETIME` in SQL Server is ***not*** stored as a **string**! It's stored as a 8-byte binary value - therefore, you cannot just use `LIKE` against it, obviously....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's no direct support for LIKE operator against `DATETIME`
>   variables

You can Convert it Into varchar as You suggested

```
select * from booking
where convert(varchar(50), BookingDate, 120) like '%11%'
```

Here If You want to check with Month then use `DatePart`

```
select * from booking
where DATEPART(M,BookingDate)=11
```

OR

You can Use datepart,datename,etc in built functions to retrieve as what you needs

[CHECK HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx)